# Cannot inject directly into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to setup angular in mu app with really basic code, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

What I have is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

    <head>
        <!-- Other JS files here including jQuery!! -->
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

In `app.js` I have:

```
var blaat11 = angular.module('test', []);

blaat11.controller('TestController', [$scope, function ($scope) {
    var aa = $scope.test;
}]);
```

But I'm getting the error I posted earlier. I want to inject services into my controller like that. I've done it before like this and never had any trouble with it.

Anyone any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `$scope` in quotes. This is used for mapping of the Dependency injections in case of minifying the code. As the `$scope` outside of the controller is not defined, the error is thrown.

```
blaat11.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
```